# ¿Cómo evitar que los grupos de captura de este patrón regex se superpongan, para que puedan capturar las subcadenas correctamente?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, regex, nltk

```py
import re

input_text = "En esta alejada ciudad por la tarde circulan muchos camiones con aquellos acoplados rojos, grandes y bastante pesados, llevándolos por esos trayectos bastante empedrados, polvorientos, y un tanto arenosos. Y incluso bastante desde lejos ya se les puede ver." #example string

list_verbs_in_this_input = ["serías", "serían", "sería", "ser", "es", "llevándoles", "llevándole", "llevándolos", "llevándolo", "circularías", "circularía", "circulando", "circulan", "circula", "consiste", "consistían", "consistía", "consistió", "visualizar", "ver", "empolvarle", "empolvar", "verías", "vería", "vieron", "vió", "vio", "ver", "podrías" , "podría", "puede"]

exclude = rf"(?!\b(?:{'|'.join(list_verbs_in_this_input)})\b)"
direct_subject_modifiers, noun_pattern = exclude + r"\w+" , exclude + r"\w+"

modifier_connectors = r"(?:(?:(?:a[úu]n|todav[íi]a|incluso)\s+|)(?:bastante|(?:de\s*gran|bastante|un\s*tanto|un\s*poco|)\s*(?:m[áa]s|menos))\s+|)"

#enumeration_of_noun_modifiers = direct_subject_modifiers + "(?:" + modifier_connectors  + direct_subject_modifiers + "){2,}"
#enumeration_of_noun_modifiers = direct_subject_modifiers + "(?:" + modifier_connectors  + direct_subject_modifiers + ")*"
enumeration_of_noun_modifiers = r"(?:" + "(?:(?:,\s*|)y|(?:,\s*|)y|,)\s*" + direct_subject_modifiers + modifier_connectors + r")*"

#sentence_capture_pattern = r"(?:aquellas|aquellos|aquella|aquel|los|las|el|la|esos|esas|este|ese|otros|otras|otro|otra)\s+" + noun_pattern + r"\s+" + enumeration_of_noun_modifiers
sentence_capture_pattern = r"(?:aquellas|aquellos|aquella|aquel|los|las|el|la|esos|esas|este|ese|otros|otras|otro|otra)\s+" + noun_pattern + modifier_connectors + direct_subject_modifiers + r"\s+(?:" + enumeration_of_noun_modifiers + r"|)"

input_text = re.sub(sentence_capture_pattern, r"((NOUN)'\g<0>')", input_text, flags=re.I|re.U)
print(repr(input_text)) # --> output
```

Este patrón logra hacer algunas capturas solo cuando en el patrón en `sentence_capture_pattern` cambia `r"\s+"` a `r"\s*"`. Creo que es un problema donde las substrings que los grupos de captura deberían capturar se "superponen", aunque no estoy seguro de cómo evitarlo.

El mecanismo que deben seguir los grupos de captura para asignar la información identificada debe ser el siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tenga en cuenta que lo que siempre debe capturar el patrón almacenado en la variable `modifier_connectors` es totalmente opcional, ya que puede aparecer o no.

En este caso este tipo de coincidencias se dan 2 veces, aunque podrían darse más, por lo que realiza 2 reorganizaciones de la información. Entonces obtienes esta string **output correcto**:

```
"En esta alejada ciudad por la tarde circulan muchos camiones con ((NOUN)'aquellos acoplados rojos, grandes y bastante pesados'), llevándolos por ((NOUN)'esos trayectos bastante empedrados, polvorientos, y un tanto arenosos'). Y incluso bastante desde lejos ya se les puede ver."
```

Quizás usar NLTK sea una opción pero no estoy seguro como podría capturar estos grupos de captura usándole, y a la vez obtener los mismos resultados.

---

EDIT **3**, tras una modificación en el código esta da algunos nuevos resultados, pero aun no el correcto pero si mas cercano a este

```py
import re

input_text = "En esta alejada ciudad por la tarde circulan muchos camiones con aquellos acoplados rojos, grandes y bastante pesados, llevándolos por esos trayectos bastante empedrados, polvorientos, y un tanto arenosos. Y incluso bastante desde lejos ya se les puede ver." #example string

list_verbs_in_this_input = ["serías", "serían", "sería", "ser", "es", "llevándoles", "llevándole", "llevándolos", "llevándolo", "circularías", "circularía", "circulando", "circulan", "circula", "consiste", "consistían", "consistía", "consistió", "visualizar", "ver", "empolvarle", "empolvar", "verías", "vería", "vieron", "vió", "vio", "ver", "podrías" , "podría", "puede"]

exclude = rf"(?!\b(?:{'|'.join(list_verbs_in_this_input)})\b)"
direct_subject_modifiers, noun_pattern = exclude + r"\w+" , exclude + r"\w+"

modifier_connectors = r"(?:(?:a[úu]n|todav[íi]a|incluso)\s+|)\s*(?:de|)\s*(?:gran\s+|bastante\s*(?:m[áa]s|menos|)\s+|(?:un\s*(?:tanto|poco)|)\s*(?:m[áa]s|menos)\s+|)" #its occurrence is optional

enumeration_of_noun_modifiers = r"(?:" + "(?:(?:,\s*|)y|,)\s*" + modifier_connectors + direct_subject_modifiers + r"\s*" + r")*"

sentence_capture_pattern = r"(?:aquellas|aquellos|aquella|aquel|los|las|el|la|esos|esas|este|ese|otros|otras|otro|otra)\s+" + noun_pattern + r"\s+" + modifier_connectors + direct_subject_modifiers + r"(?:(?:,\s*|)y|(?:,\s*|)y|,)\s*(?:\s*" + enumeration_of_noun_modifiers + r"|)"

input_text = re.sub(sentence_capture_pattern, r"((NOUN)'\g<0>')", input_text, flags=re.I|re.U)
print(repr(input_text)) # --> output
```

Este es el resultado erroneo que esta dando ahora

```
"En esta alejada ciudad por la tarde circulan muchos camiones con ((NOUN)'aquellos acoplados rojos, ')grandes y bastante pesados, llevándolos por ((NOUN)'esos trayectos bastante empedrados, ')polvorientos, y un tanto arenosos. Y incluso bastante desde lejos ya se les puede ver."
```

Comment: Me da curiosidad saber en que proyecto trabajas, cual es el objetivo último que buscas.

Comment: @CandidMoe Un sistema de analisis de texto que identifique en los inputs de texto centrandose en la persona(el sujeto junto a los adjetivos que le describan), la propia accion(los verbos los identifico con spacy), el tiempo de la accion(solo si es especificado), y el lugar(solo si es especificado). De este modo, puede extraer informacion(yo creo que con esos 4 aspectos fundamentales ya es bastante) sin requerir de redes neuronales que consumen demasiados recursos. Comparandole con un modelo de Naive Bayes, puedo extraer info con meno de 500 mb de Ram

Comment: @CandidMoe La verdad, es que la regex de la pregunta para mi esta bien, aunque  no entiendo porque las regex no capturan las subcadenas correctas. Si se te ocurre algo me re ayudarias

Comment: Y dentro de esa aplicación, ¿qué rol juega el código que muestras? Supongo que parsea el texto de entrada y trata de clasificar los lexemas. ¿Correcto?

Comment: Una manera de no requerir de buscar lexemas es usando un algoritmo de comparación de cadenas, es decir, si coincide mas del 70% asumiré que se trata de una misma palabra (pero eso lo usaría para ver si la info que extrajo previamente se parece a una nueva información).

Comment: @CandidMoe  En especifico el código de la pregunta, es la parte de detección de los objetos y sus descripciones. En otras palabras busco "encapsular" la subcadena `"aquel|aquella|ese" "un sustantivo" "verde", bastante "grande", "alto" , y ...`. El problema estoy casi seguro que lo tiene algo en `sentence_capture_pattern` , el tema es que debe ser algo relacionado al comportamiento greedy de las regex de los sustantivos y adjetivos `\w+`

Comment: En el código tenés `exclude + r"\w+"` ... No deberían ser espacios (o al menos tener espacios en el medio)?

Comment: Sería mucho más sencillo responderte si generás un [mcve], mostrando el regex final en una versión simplificada con menos palabras y un ejemplo donde falle

Comment: Probablemente el error esté en las estructuras `(?:a|b|c|)\s*` ... Sería más práctico usar `(?:(?:a|b|c)\s+)?`

Comment: @Pollo La "versión verificable" es el propio output deseado (lo que esta al final de la pregunta), y no una versión con menos palabras. El objetivo es identificar esas descripciones y luego la función `re.sub()` , las encapsularía dentro de paréntesis `((NOUN)'y el texto que identifique para ese patron de busqueda')`, tal como se indica en el ejemplo de la pregunta. Respecto al ejemplo donde falle, es el propio `input_text`, ya que si tu lo pruebas notaras que no capturara nada, a excepcion que modifiques algunos `\w+` con `\w*`

Comment: Verificable sí, perfecto... Falta "mínimo" ... Estoy diciendo que a mí no me dan ganas de evaluar toooodoooo tu código para entender cómo queda el patrón llego de ser evaluado, cuando perfectamente podrías presentar una versión simplificada en la pregunta

Comment: @Pollo En esos casos estoy excluyendo esas palabras de la captura `exclude + r"\w+"`, es decir que el grupo de captura capturaría `r"\w+"`, si y solo si, no esta presente ninguna de las palabras que estén en las opciones almacenadas en la variable `exclude`.- Es decir, no hay espacio en medio porque el objetivo es evitar la presencia de las palabras excluidas y no concatenarlas.

Comment: @Pollo Es que ya esta simplificada, de hecho ya estan hechas las exclusiones y los verbos ya estan en una lista, sin necesidad de identificarlos usando Spacy. De todos modos, si consideras quitar algo, dime y lo reduzco. Pero puse el codigo para que textualmente puedas replicar los mismos resultados que yo. Ademas hice el diagrama de flechas para que se entienda la logica que estoy intentando armar.

Comment: @Pollo Es que `exclude` esta preparado para bloquear el patrón en el caso de que aparezca un verbo de esa lista. Es decir, si por ejemplo... con `direct_subject_modifiers` o con`noun_pattern` se capturase la subcadena `"llevándoles"` , y esta efectivamente está presente dentro de `exclude` entonces se anula la captura y la regex ya debería entender que allí no puede haber una coincidencia, y continua su búsqueda pero "reiniciando" la coincidencia, ya que las condiciones no le estarán dadas para que coincida (almenos no alli).

Comment: En `enumeration_of_noun_modifiers` estás usando `direct_subject_modifiers + modifier_connectors` ... No hay ningún espacio en el medio

Comment: @Pollo Me di cuenta de una cosa e invertí `direct_subject_modifiers + modifier_connectors` a `modifier_connectors + direct_subject_modifiers`, ahora por lo menos captura algunas cosas, ahi lo añadí al final de la pregunta, aunque la regex "se traba" mas adelante... :(

Comment: Insisto, Sigue habiendo problemas con los espacios, especialmente cuando usás alternancia con una opción vacía `(x|y|)\s*`. Si llevaras todo a una estructura como `(?:(?:a|b|c)\s+)?` probablemente puedas solucionarlo

Comment: @Pollo Definitivamente el problema esta en la estructuración del patrón  `sentence_capture_pattern`, es decir cuando se concatenan todos los subpatrones, ahora estaba intentando con algo asi `sentence_capture_pattern = r"(?:aquellas|aquellos|aquella|aquel|los|las|el|la|esos|esas|este|ese|otros|otras|otro|otra)\s+" + noun_pattern + modifier_connectors + direct_subject_modifiers + r"(?:(?:,\s*|)y|(?:,\s*|)y|,)\s*(?:" + enumeration_of_noun_modifiers + r"|)"`  pero aun tiene fallos

Comment: Tenés `noun_pattern + modifier_connectors` ... `noun_pattern` es básicamente `\w+` ... Y no hay espacios antes de `modifier_connectors`

Comment: @Pollo He editado nuevamente el código, ahora da resultados algo mejores `((NOUN)'aquellos acoplados rojos, ')grandes y bastante pesados` , pero hay algo que genera que el patrón de búsqueda `sentence_capture_pattern` se detenga antes de tiempo, cuando aun le falta capturar un poquito mas. Tendria que haber llegado a capturar hasta la parte de `"y bastante pesados"` inclusive, y recien luego de ella cortar la captura

Comment: @Pollo He hecho una tercera edición, obteniendo `((NOUN)'aquellos acoplados rojos, ')grandes y bastante pesados`, por algun motivo el patrón de búsqueda se sigue trabando, luego de `rojos, `